# \end{tabu} in \newcommand

Tags: macros, tabu

I want to put `\end{tabu}` within a `\newcommand`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabu}

\newcommand
{\tableBegin}[1]
{
    \begin{tabu}[#1]
    % some other stuff
}

\newcommand
{\tableEnd}
{\end{tabu}}

\begin{document}

\tableBegin{ccc}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
a & b & c
\tableEnd
%\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

But when I use `\tableEnd` instead of `\end{tabu}` I get get following error:
`! Missing $ inserted.`

Comment: tabu (like AMS evironments and tabularx etc), grabs its body as an argument so explicitly looks for `\end{tabu}` in the source. It is possible to work around that but it is simpler not to and just use the documented environment name. `\tableBegin/End` is very unlike LaTeX conventions why not define a new environment?

Answer (score 5):

`tabu` (like AMS environments and `tabularx` etc), grabs its body as an argument so explicitly looks for `\end{tabu}` in the source. It is possible to work around that but it is simpler not to, and just use the documented environment name.

`\tableBegin/End` is very unlike LaTeX conventions why not define a new environment?