# LaTeX not recognizing \end found in a \newcommand

Tags: tables, macros, tabu

I'm trying to both start and end a table with \newcommand.  I'd like to switch to using `\EndTableSetupFourColumns` (as it removes several warnings and is easier to understand for other readers) but for some reason LaTeX does not seem to recognize the `\end{tabu}` found within, so I have to insert it manually as seen below.

This problem seems to be limited to tabu - when I was using tabulars I did not have this issue.  I looked through the tabu documentation and could not find anything that would indicate this wouldn't work.

Looking at [\end{tabu} in \newcommand](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108107/endtabu-in-newcommand?rq=1) shows that it won't work, however, it is something I'd like to work around for code readability, if nothing else.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable,tabu}

\newcommand{\TableSetupFourColumns}{%
\rowcolors{2}{gray!25}{white}
\begin{tabu} to \textwidth {lccX}
    \rowcolor{gray!50}}

\newcommand{\EndTableSetupFourColumns}{%
\end{tabu}}

\begin{document}

\section{Test 1}
This is text.\par \noindent
\TableSetupFourColumns
    Test            & test  & test  & test\\
\end{tabu}
%\EndTableSetupFourColumns

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tabu` needs to "see" `\end{tabu}`; it cannot be hidden in a macro. You're better served by defining a new environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable,tabu}

\newenvironment{tabu4}
  {\rowcolors{2}{gray!25}{white}
   \begin{tabu} to \textwidth {lccX}
   \rowcolor{gray!50}}
  {\end{tabu}}

\begin{document}

\section{Test 1}
This is text.

\medskip

\noindent
\begin{tabu4}
    Test            & test  & test  & test\\
    Test            & test  & test  & test\\
    Test            & test  & test  & test\\
    Test            & test  & test  & test\\
    Test            & test  & test  & test\\
    Test            & test  & test  & test\\
\end{tabu4}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.  However, when I perform the same with longtabu I'm getting a Misplaced \cr error at each \end tag.

I'll see if I can get a MNWE of that up.

Comment: @LearningLaTeX I'm afraid that `longtabu` is a different matter.

Comment: Well that would explain my issue.  Can I not perform this with longtabu at all then?  Would using `\newcommand` work for longtabu, or could I get it working with `\newenvironment`?

Comment: @LearningLaTeX If in the example I change `tabu4` to `longtabu4` and `tabu` in the definition to `longtabu`, I don't have any problem.

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be an interaction between my `fancyhdr`'s `\fancyhead` and `\fancyfoot` when the table is big enough to span more than one page.  I've got a MNWE that I'll post if I can't figure out how to fix it myself.

Comment: For reference, I was running into the issues found here (as well as the solution): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49622/longtabu-and-scrpage2-line-breaks-in-page-header-cause-compilation-errors